# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized comment on youtube video

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually i want to post the message on YouTube video by using below mention API which I got from console Google API.

POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "parentId": "UgyYTPS4iUnQMdFHjaB4AaABAg",
    "textOriginal": "abcdefgh"
  }
}
```

I don't know how to pass this in postman to test this API.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new request in Postman you can simply select the Headers tab under the url textbox and put there your parameters (key and value).
You can also select the Type of request from the dropdown menu near the url textbox (in your case it would be POST).